# Cannot connect to MySQL via XAMP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

*It has been headache for me to connect to MySQL.*

### Background:

OS: Windows 7 (64 bits)

I have been trying to connect to the MYSQL. I am using XAMPP control panel v3.1.0.

The Apache is working fine and I can run my PHP programs on it to upload and move files and all.

I connect the MySQL and it shows in XAMP and it is running :

> 12:27:48 PM  [mysql]  Attempting to start MySQL app... 12:27:48 PM 
>   [mysql]   Status change detected: running

I logged in to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and it did not ask me a password as XAMPP did not ask me for any password during the time of `installation`.

I created username `pingu` from `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and gave it a password as well.

### My questions:

1.) I do not know how to login as a user.

I get the following error when I use: `mysql> -u pingu -p;`

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near `'-u pingu -p'` at line 1

I have even tried:

```
mysql>  -u root -p admin;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near `'-u root -p admin'` at line 1

2.) When I try to create a database from the command line MySQL it gives me the following error:

> MySQL> CREATE DATABASE publications; ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied
>   for user ''@'local host' to database 'publications'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First locate your XAMPP install `C:\Program Files\xampp` for a full install.

Open a new Command Prompt Window:

- Click Start
- Type "cmd"
- Hit enter

In Command prompt go to the XAMPP directory do not include the `C:` part

`cd \path\to\xampp`

Start MySql:

`mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u pingu -p`

Comment: Hi Squirly,I tried but it does not work. 
I am already in the mysql\Bin and executing the mysql.exe BUT it does not accepts the -u pingu -p;

Comment: Can you add the exact output in your CLI window?

From your question it looks like you're running the `-u pingu -p` part of the command in the MySql Cli and not appended to the mysql.exe client program in command prompt, as in my example.

Comment: Try running `mysql.exe -u pingu -p` in one line in the mysql/bin directory. If it fails post the full content of your command prompt window in your question, including the command you used to start mysql.exe.

Comment: I am in c:\XAMPP\mysql\bin and opened the mysql.exe from there which opens up the mysql command prompt. ( have tried it through command prompt as well)
Following is the error I get :

mysql> -u pingu -p;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near '-u pingu -p' at line 1

Comment: Follow my directions exactly.
Hit start (that odd circle thing), type `cmd`, hit enter, type `cd \XAMPP\mysql\bin`, hit enter, type `mysql.exe -u pingu -p` (this is one line!), hit enter.

Comment: COOL BANANAS !!!
Thanks buddy , it is working now :)
I Have been using oracle Sql and didn't know how to get in there.
so in this one we are running the mysql.exe as user <username> -p as <password>

Comment: I hope it works when I try to connect it through PHP.
Much appreciated your help.